# php how to check if condition for unicode password

Tags: php

Iam new to php. I need to check whether newpassword(unicoded) variable is empty or null. If the value is a normal string, i could have checked as `if($newpass){echo 'inside if'}`  but unforutnately, $newpassword value is getting a different value.

**Below is the code:** (which is already written by someone, i need to fix it)

```
                                if($newPassword != ""){
print_r('inside if');
                                $userdata["unicodePwd"] = $newPassword;                             
                                }

var_export($userdata);
```

I am sure there is something wrong in the code, but iam not able to fix it. Ultimately I should be able to check if $newPassword have some value, then it should go inside if. Sorry if its a dumb query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST['userpassword'])) {
    // password sent from client
    $userPassword = trim($_POST['userpassword']);
    if ($userPassword !== '') {
        // userPassword isn't empty, and spaces have been removed
        $utf8Password = utf8_encode($userPassword);
    }
}
```